# Weird Compiler Error in Parser Code

Tags: c, parsing, compiler-errors, undefined-behavior

**Parser.h**

```
enum { PLUS, MINUS, DIVIDE, MULTIPLY, NUMBER, END } type;

int token;

/* parsing functions */
void parse_token (void);
```

**Parser.c**

```
void get_token (void)
{       
     token++;   
     parse_token(); /* LINE 11 */
}

void parse_token (void) /* LINE 14 */
{
    if ( strchr ("1234567890.", token) )
        type = NUMBER;

    else if ( strchr ("+", token) )
        type = PLUS;

    else if ( strchr ("-", token) )
        type = MINUS;

    else if ( strchr ("/", token) )
        type = DIVIDE;

    else if ( strchr ("*",token) )
        type = MULTIPLY;

    else if ( token == '\0' )
        type = END;
    else 
        show_error(strcat("Couldn't parse token : ", token));
}
```

**The Errors**

```
parser.c:14:6: warning: conflicting types for ‘parse_token’ [enabled by default]
parser.c:11:2: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘parse_token’ was here
parser.c: In function ‘parse_token’:
parser.c:16:2: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strchr’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/include/string.h:235:14: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
parser.c:17:3: error: ‘type’ undeclared (first use in this function)
parser.c:17:3: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
parser.c:17:10: error: ‘NUMBER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
parser.c:19:2: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strchr’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/include/string.h:235:14: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
parser.c:20:10: error: ‘PLUS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
parser.c:22:2: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strchr’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/include/string.h:235:14: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
parser.c:23:10: error: ‘MINUS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
parser.c:25:2: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strchr’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/include/string.h:235:14: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
parser.c:26:10: error: ‘DIVIDE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
parser.c:28:2: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strchr’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/include/string.h:235:14: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
parser.c:29:10: error: ‘MULTIPLY’ undeclared (first use in this function)
parser.c:32:10: error: ‘END’ undeclared (first use in this function)
parser.c: In function ‘show_error’:
parser.c:40:2: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
```

I'm utterly bamboozled. :(.

Any help?

Comment: Which ones are lines 14 and 11 of parser.c?

Comment: have you included the parser.h? 
parser.c:17:10: error: ‘NUMBER’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: Just for the record, it's not parsing, it's [lexical analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis). And the tool is not a parser but a lexer.

Comment: @Jan: can't lexical analysis be seen as parsing tokens that happen to be characters into a very simple language that consists of a sequence of tokens?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, that's a valid point. For convenience such a special case of parsing is usually called lexing or scanning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One you get it to compile (by including the header, as Luchian Grigore said), you'll find that you can't do `strcat()` on a constant string.

The constant string is allocated in read-only memory, and can't be modified. And even if you could modify it, you would be overwriting other things in memory.

Answer (score 3):

You're not including your header, so there's no way for the translation unit to know about the declarations of `type` and `token`.

You need:

```
#include "Parser.h"
```

at the beginning of the implementation file.